# gdb how to print vector<bool> value

Tags: c++, command-line, stl, gdb

I just debuging c++ program and I have value

```
vector<bool> B(n, 0);
```

My question is how to print it value in gdb console? Because eclipse IDE is not too smart to present it in redable format.

When I had integer vector I can do something like:

```
 printf "%x %x %x", B[0], B[1], B[2]...
```

so I was able to read this vector. But with boolean is hard because printf didn't have format to print it, also I can't type in console p B[0]; p B[1] ...

So maybe anybody has idea how to debug stuff like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/?kw=bitset) is a far better option than `vector<bool>`.

Among other reasons because it supports stream operators, so you can just stream this thing out.

This of course assumes that the data type is under your control.

With `printf` you can use `bitset`'s [`to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/to_string/)

**EDIT in response to [Enrico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301336/gdb-how-to-print-vectorbool-value/27302079?noredirect=1#comment52961248_27302079):**

In the event that a `bitset` cannot be used it is possible to print `vector<bool>` elements from GDB, but how a `vector<bool>` is implemented in GCC needs to be understood. `vector<bool>`'s index operator is *not* returning a `bool` but a [`vector<bool>::reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) which is not a `bool` but provides a conversion operator to a `bool`.

In GCC this `reference` has a `_M_p` member which is a pointer to the storage allocated for the `vector<bool>` class and a `_M_mask` member which can be used to mask all but the indexed bit. The combination of these two yields either a zero or non-zero value. Zero means the bit is unset and a non-zero means the bit is set.

For a `vector<bool> foo` you could print this combination with the GDB command:

> print *(foo[i]._M_p) & foo[i]._M_mask

Comment: Even though it is a nice suggestion this is not what the question was about. bitset needs compile-time size while vector<bool> doesn't, so there are a few times where bitset won't fit, and I'm having the same issue here.

Comment: @Enrico Fair point. I've updated to explain how poor souls who are trapped in a `vector<bool>` implementation can accomplish this (on GCC).

Comment: The answer does not seem right. With a vector of size 2 I get using i=1 the result (unsigned long) 2. Does any nonzero result represent a true? If so, the for clarity the answer should be `print !!(*(foo[i]._M_p) & foo[i]._M_mask)`.

Comment: @rwst It has been quite some time since I've worked in gdb. But yes I do seem to remember that non-zero means that the bit is set, as it says in my answer. Your comment is helpful though as it would take the integer and turn it to an actual "true"/"false". If you care to add an answer, you'd certainly get an upvote from me!